# How to convert long/lat LAZ to coordinate system?

Tags: convert, epsg, utm, canada

I have a Canadian lidar LAZ file, and it is in long/lat based in UTM10, sourced from LidarBC (https://governmentofbc.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=d06b37979b0c4709b7fcf2a1ed458e03).

I need to pass this into another app, but this second app expects data in a coordinate system with an EPSG code.  To me, as the end user, the EPSG code is not critical, I just need a relevant code.

How can I convert the data file?  Apologies if this is a stupid question, I am not a lidar expert.  Up to now, most lidar files have been expressed using an EPSG system.

Comment: Please post a link (DropBox, WeTransfer, etc) to your LAZ.

Comment: UTM is projected not lat/long and there are EPSG code for it : https://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=utm+10N&srtext=Search

Comment: Thanks @J.R, I tried using 26910 and 32610, but the second app still errored.  I am a little bit out of my depth here.

Comment: Here is a link to the LAZ files for @Pointdump ... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Pltc4IqsfnHXC4bVAPIdo6Yl-apkYV-3?usp=sharing

Comment: Steve, Using lasinfo in lastools reads the header, which shows the coordinate system as NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N + CGVD2013 height. So that would be EPSG:6653.

Comment: Thanks @Pointdump, that is very helpful!  I am afk shortly but will try this tonight.

Comment: @Pointdump - This worked!  Could you enter it as an answer so I can credit it to you please?  Now the second app barfed at the file size, but it at least accepts the EPSG and gives me sensible visualisation, which is a step closer to success.  Sweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lasinfo in lastools, projection information in the header of the LAZ file shows:

```
COMPD_CS["NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N + CGVD2013 height - CGG2013 (meters)",PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6140"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["meter",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3157"]],VERT_CS["CGVD2013 height - CGG2013 (meters)",VERT_DATUM["Canadian Geodetic Vertical Datum of 2013",2005,AUTHORITY["EPSG","1127"]],UNIT["meter",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Up",UP],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6647"]]]
```

Comment: Superb, many thanks.  Am now using lasClip to trim the files, much obliged!